# Android: does custom view not used "from xml" need to have default constructors?

Tags: android, serialization, view, lifecycle

I have a custom view that I always create in code and add to the views hierarchy in code, so it is never included from xml (I know that the next person maintaining my code after may want to use it from xml, but let's assume for the sake of simplicity that this will never happen).

My view does not have the standard constructors ((Contex), (Context, AttributeSet)), my constructor has some extra params. Is this ok? I know the standard constructors would be called when the view is included from XML, but as mentioned above I do not use the view from xml. I have a doubt however what would happen if there is low memory situation, my activity is killed but the view hierarchy preserved - would not those constructors be needed since Android calls them while recreating view instances? I tested that by setting in the simulator to kill activities when I leave them - in spite of lack of those default constructors my app does not crash and the custom view looks normally. My doubt is still there since I do not know how it really works.

In other words my question is:
1. In the situation described above, in what form the view hierarchy is preserved? Is it just serialized? Written to XML? Any other way?
2. When the view hierarchy is resurrected, how the view objects are recreated (Default constructor called? Constructor with Context argument called? Some other way?)

Thanks!

Comment: i never heard of `"view objects recreation"`: you have to build view tree when `Activity#onCreate` is called again

Comment: If you check here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState you will see that "The default implementation of this method saves information about the state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView." So it seem that some information about the view hierarchy is preserved, and my question is basically how exactly actual view instances are recreated from this preserved information, what constructors are called in the process etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the situation described above, in what form the view hierarchy is preserved?

It is not preserved.

> When the view hierarchy is resurrected, how the view objects are recreated

By however your code creates them.

> does custom view not used “from xml” need to have default constructors?

You need whatever constructor(s) you are using. Layout inflation requires the two-parameter constructor (`Context`, `AttributeSet`), last I checked. But, if you are not using that, you do not need to implement it.

Comment: Please check my comment above where I give a reference to Android documentation about view state preserving - this is what I mean.

Comment: @LukaszIndyk: View *state* != view *hierarchy*. The view state is held onto in another process in the form of a series of `Parcelable` objects. Android does not recreate the view hierarchy after a configuration change or process termination. However, Android will attempt to restore the view state, after you have recreated the view hierarchy, for the sorts of things that are mentioned in the documentation that you cite (e.g., text in an `EditText`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you describe how exactly Android restores the view state? I mean at some point I had my activity and views, they got destroyed due to lack of memory, during destruction text in EditText was saved by Android. Then I go back to my activity, onCreate is called, i create my views in the same way like initially and have them - but they are empty. How the previous text of in the EditText, that is now a new instance, is initialized from the saved state?

Comment: @LukaszIndyk: Well, the big thing is that the ID values have to match. If you are creating widgets dynamically, and you want Android to hold onto their state as part of default `onSavedInstanceState()` processing, you need to assign unique IDs to them.

Comment: Ok, let's say I assign the ID correctly. Can you answer my previous question how exactly the saved text from the previous instance of EditText is assigned to the new EditText instance that I just created in onCreate called on my fresh, new instance of my activity?

Comment: @LukaszIndyk: See `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` on `View`. You can see implementations in most stateful widgets by looking at the source code. Here is a simple `ColorMixer` widget I wrote a few years back that demonstrates it: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Views/ColorMixer/src/com/commonsware/android/colormixer/ColorMixer.java

Comment: Ok great. This answers my question fully :) Thank you so much!